# How to enable unsafe header parsing in .net 7

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-7.0

I have this code to enable unsafe header parsing

```
Public Shared Function SetAllowUnsafeHeaderParsing20() As Boolean
    'Get the assembly that contains the internal class
    Dim aNetAssembly As Assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(GetType(System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection))
    If (Not (aNetAssembly) Is Nothing) Then
        'Use the assembly in order to get the internal type for the internal class
        Dim aSettingsType As Type = aNetAssembly.GetType("System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSectionInternal")
        If (Not (aSettingsType) Is Nothing) Then
            'Use the internal static property to get an instance of the internal settings class.
            'If the static instance isn't created allready the property will create it for us.
            Dim anInstance As Object = aSettingsType.InvokeMember("Section", (BindingFlags.Static _
                            Or (BindingFlags.GetProperty Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)), Nothing, Nothing, New Object(-1) {})
            If (Not (anInstance) Is Nothing) Then
                'Locate the private bool field that tells the framework is unsafe header parsing should be allowed or not
                Dim aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing As FieldInfo = aSettingsType.GetField("useUnsafeHeaderParsing", (BindingFlags.NonPublic Or BindingFlags.Instance))
                If (Not (aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing) Is Nothing) Then
                    aUseUnsafeHeaderParsing.SetValue(anInstance, True)
                    Return True
                End If

            End If

        End If

    End If

    Return False
End Function
```

Then

I upgraded to .NET 7

I got a complain that System.Net is no longer there so the code have compile error.

It's a similar code that can be found in

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff098248-551c-4da9-8ba5-358a9f8ccc57/how-do-i-enable-useunsafeheaderparsing-from-code-net-20?forum=netfxnetcom

How should I replace it?

I still want unsafe parsing. Some json that I grab won't work without it.

Comment: I believe the intention behind this setting was to allow a grace period whilst getting both client and server to *properly respect HTTP rules*. Not to forever opt out of following the specs. Why haven't you been using this time to e.g. update your protocol to not place inappropriate items in the headers?

Comment: Can I check: you're updating from .net framework (some version) to .net 7? Non-public reflection is very likely to be unstable over such a huge gap, even if the types existed. What specific behaviour change is it you're looking to workaround? You mention JSON, but JSON and header parsing don't usually overlap...? Is the problem that you have unescaped raw json as a presumably-invalid http header? or ..?

Comment: I think some API didn't work if I enabled it. That's all. I am not even sure whether that's still the case.